# How to show two table data in a view using Eloquent Relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two Table names are **User** and **Role** Table. I have set manyTomany relations between them using pivot table name **Role_User** in Laravel Eloquent.
Now, I want to show both table data in together a view using Eloquent Relationship.(e.g. I want to show in my view a user from **users** table contain which role in **roles** table )

**Here, is my eloquent relations.**

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

**My, Eloquent Relationship Query.**

```
    $users=User::with('roles')->get();

    return view('admin',compact('users'));
```

**I'm try in my View.**

```
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->roles->name}}</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `$user->roles`, you get a collection of the roles back. So if you want to display them all in a single string, all you have to do is implode the collection on that string:

`<td>{{$user->roles->implode('name', ', ')}}</td>`

Answer (score 1):

Your `$user->rules` is instance of Collection of Role model. You can use one more foreach:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    //do something with user
    @foreach($user->roles as $role)
        {{$role->name}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will work in Laravel 5.0 and above**
If we have two Model User and Mark. Then Inside the User Model make a function for relation with Mark. Example

```
public function marks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Mark');
    }
```

So, If you want to display the User name will all his marks. Then inside the controller perform following way.

```
    public function getUserMarks(){

        $result = User::select('email', 'name')->where('email', 'usermail@example.com')->with(['marks'])->get();
        return view('welcome', compact('results'));
    }
```